# When does a right triangle with integral perimeter and area have rational sides?

Tags: triangles, square-numbers

When does a right triangle
with integral perimeter and area
have rational sides?

First find
the sides a and b
in terms of
area $A$ and perimeter $P$.

$A = ab/2
$, so 
$ab = 2A$.

$\begin{array}{rl}\\
P 
&= a+b+\sqrt {a^2+b^2}\\
\text{so}\\
a^2+b^2 
&=(P-(a+b))^2\\
&=P^2-2P(a+b)+(a+b)^2\\
&=P^2-2P(a+b)+a^2+2ab+b^2\\
&=P^2-2P(a+b)+a^2+4A+b^2\\
\text{so}\\
2P(a+b)
&=P^2+4A\\
\text{or}\\
a+b
&=(P^2+4A)/(2P)\\
\end{array}
$

so $a$ and $b$
 are the roots of

$x^2-(P^2+4A)x/(2P)+2A = 0\\
\text{or}\\
x^2-(P/2+2A/P)x+2A = 0
$

The discriminant
$d$ satisfies

$\begin{array}\\
d^2
&=(P/2+2A/P)^2-8A\\
&=P^2/4+2A+(2A/P)^2-8A\\
&=(P/2)^2-6A+(2A/P)^2\\
&=\dfrac{P^4-24AP^2+16A^2}{4P^2}\\
&=\dfrac{D^2}{4P^2}\\
\text{so}\\
a, b
&=(P/2+2A/P \pm d)/2\\
&=(P/2+2A/P \pm D/(2P))/2\\
&=P/4+A/P \pm D/(4P)\\
&=(P^2+4A \pm D)/(4P)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$P^4-24AP^2+16A^2$
must be a square,
but I don't know how to solve this.

Its discriminant is
$24^2-4\cdot 16
=576-64
=512$
which seems significant.

Also
$P^4-24AP^2+16A^2
=(P^2-12A)^2-144A^2+16A^2
=(P^2-12A)^2-128A^2
$
so we want this 
to be a square.
Again, I don't know how to do this.

Your turn.

Comment: Hint: $$(2a+1)^2+(2a^2+2a)^2=(2a^2+2a+1)^2$$

Comment: Please elucidate.

Comment: From the equation above we find that the area is $a(a+1)(2a+1)$ and perimeter $2(a+1)(2a+1) $. These are integral for some integer $a$ and also when $a=\frac12$.

Comment: Actually the area is not - seems I have made an error! o.O

Comment: Such triangles are called [Heronian triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle), they can be explicitly parametrized.

Comment: Why not work the other way around? We know which right-angled triangles have integer sides and hence which have rational sides. Now require that the perimeter and area be integers.